# correct way of using os.path.join() in python

Tags: python

I came across this python function os.path.join(). I wanted to know which was a preferred method of using it.

```
os.path.join(r'C:\\' , r'some_dir_in_C_folder')
```

or

```
print os.path.join("C:\\" , "some_dir_in_C_folder\\")
```

TIA

Comment: There are multiple differences between the two code snippets, and it's not clear which difference is important to you. Is it the `print`? Or the raw strings? Or the backslash at the end of the path?

Comment: not print actually. i wanted to ultimately walk through this saved path when need arises. When i say saved, i mean i'd store it in a variable.

Comment: the top one is correct ... the point of `os.path.join` is that you dont need to worry about the separator ... as such using it largely defeats the purpose ... `os.path.join` is just a convenience wrapper around  `os.path.sep.join(["PATH","DIR1","DIR2",...])`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

both are incorrect, the correct usage is(for eg: `c:/programs/myfiles/cat.txt`:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.path.join('C:/' , 'programs','myfiles','cat.txt') 
'C:/programs/myfiles/cat.txt'
```

Comment: OP's second version is somewhat correct. Your version is incorrect, and doesn't give the result you posted for me. I assume you didn't run it on Windows.

Comment: @interjay as `joran beasley` said `the point of os.path.join is that you don't need to worry about the seperator.`

Comment: If you ran this then it wasn't on Windows. On Windows your version would give a relative path to the current directory on drive C:, which is incorrect.

Comment: The backslash after C: is required on Windows. From the documentation: Note that on Windows, since there is a current directory for each drive, os.path.join("c:", "foo") represents a path relative to the current directory on drive C: (c:foo), not c:\foo.

Comment: @interjay ok. i have updated my answer. will you try: `os.path.join('C:/' , 'programs','myfiles','cat.txt') `

Comment: This is the result i got in windows: 'C:/programs\\myfiles\\cat.txt'

Comment: @BrownieTuffy hmm... so you need `c:\\\`` instead of `c:/`. I am using linux and it is strongly recommend to use `/` instead of using `\\` you can also use some relative paths.